# Solving $\log\vert z \vert = -2\arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm struggling to solve the following equation.
$\log\vert z \vert = -2\arg(z)$

I've played around with it. Dividing by $-2$ I get
$\log\vert z \vert ^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \arg(z)$ and then taking the exponential and after that  both sides to the power of two and rearranging.

$\frac{1}{\vert z \vert} = e^{2\arg(z)} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{e^{2\arg(z)}} =  \vert z \vert  $

Since $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we can write it as $z= re^{i\theta}$ for some real number $r$ and an angle $\theta$. But $\vert z \vert = r$ and by taking the principal branch of the argument of z we can say (here I'm a little unsure, please correct me if I'm wrong) that $\arg(z) "=" Arg(z) = \theta$. Thus

$$
z= re^{i\theta} = \frac{1}{e^{2\theta}} \cdot e^{i\theta} = e^{-2\theta}e^{i\theta} = e^{\theta(i-1)}
$$

Assuming this is correct so far, now what? My idea is to solve for $\theta$ and
I've tried various things yielding nothing. Taking the logarithm on both sides. setting it equal to its explicit trigonometric expression, its Cartesian form and trying to solve etc. It feels like I'm missing something maybe obvious. Any hints and or corrections would be really appreciated. I also want to apologize for my $\LaTeX$ being somewhat rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small slip in your working:- $ z=e^{\theta(i-2)}$.

That's the answer!

Comment: A god damn typo haha. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to sort it out.

Comment: @MartinGarb It is important to note that for a given value of $\theta$, the *direction* of $z = e^{\theta(i -2)}$ will be constant for $\{\theta, \theta \pm 2\pi, \theta \pm 4\pi, \cdots\}$ while the norm $|z|$ will be changing. Therefore, the locus will be a spiral.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=re^{i\theta}$, $|z|=r$ and $\arg(z)=\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.
So
$$\log|z|=-2\arg(z)\iff \log r=-2\theta\iff r=e^{-2\theta}.$$
So $$z=e^{-2\theta}e^{i\theta}=e^{\theta(i-2)}.$$